# redirect to specific route on datapager page index change

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-routing, datapager

I have a listing page which contains a `ListView` control associated to `DataPager` control.
I have also implemented `ASP.Net WebForms URL routing`. initially when the user visits the page the url comes like

```
www.domain.com/entity/list
```

When i click on `DataPager` Page button i want the `URL` to be like

```
www.domain.com/entity/list/{Page_Number}
```

I have handled the DataPager_PagePropertiesChanging event in which i get the Current Page Index like following

```
    protected void lvRestaurants_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPage = ((RestaurantPager.StartRowIndex) / RestaurantPager.MaximumRows) + 1;
        //Response.RedirectToRoute("browserestaurantbypage", new { id_pg = CurrentPage });
        //RestaurantPager.GetRouteUrl("browserestaurantbypage", new { id_pg = CurrentPage - 1 });
        Response.RedirectToRoute("browserestaurantbypage", new { id_pg = CurrentPage});

    }
```

is it ok to call `Response.RedirectToRoute` in above event because i get the page isn't Redirecting Properly error in firefox.

my DataPager Control looks like following

```
<asp:DataPager ID="RestaurantPager" runat="server" QueryStringField='<%#Eval("ID_Restaurant") %>' 
                                PagedControlID="lvRestaurants" PageSize="10">
                                <Fields>

                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField PreviousPageText="&laquo; previous" ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                                        ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="true" />
                                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current" ButtonCount="4" />
                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField NextPageText="Next &raquo;" ShowLastPageButton="false"
                                        ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                                </Fields>
                            </asp:DataPager>
```

would you please guide me how to achieve this . Please let me know if anything is unclear in question.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect("www.domain.com/entity/whateverpage.aspx?pageNum=" + GetDestinationPageNumberFunction());

Comment: i want routed url not with the querystring

Comment: Redirect it with Session variables then